# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 auth

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm actually following SessionLoginFragment.java example from facebook sdk samples.

What I really don't understand is this:

when I make

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(fragment).setCallback(statusCallback));
```

to log my user to facebook and ask basic read permission (just to test the integration) it simply does not work.

I digged a bit with the debugger and I followed the path. If you don't put a requestCode to the OpenRequest of the session it will give it a random one (and this is ok).

openForRead (my actual session is in CREATED status) will create the permission dialog. When you hit the "Ok" button it will perform a

```
request.getStartActivityDelegate().startActivityForResult(intent, request.getRequestCode());
```

You can see the code from the fb sdk source code. Well the requestCode is the same of the session (and here's ok).

When fb log you into the system it will finish his facebook.LoginActivity and call me back my onActivityResult in my activity. The problem is that here the requestCode is different from the request's one. And I don't know why and where it comes from!

If I go into my fb account my application is there, so it means that I've done the correct auth flow that finish well. But I wont get correctly authenticated from my app because of this problem.

Do you know why and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

UPDATE WITH FLOW DETAIL:

This is the actual flow (from **fragment**):

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(fragment).setCallback(statusCallback));
```

After creating it, the request code is (always) **64206**
Now openForRead flow will call (final part)

```
request.getStartActivityDelegate().startActivityForResult(intent, request.getRequestCode());
```

That call the LoginActivity from facebook SDK and do the client/server validation/oauth

Now on my **activity** is called onActivityResult (not on the fragment but on the activity part)

and here I call

```
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

And here the requestCode is requestCode **129742**

How is it possible? As I already said, the problem in all this flow is that requestCode returned to onActivityResult is different from my pendingRequest requestCode and this break (getActiveSession().onActivityResult return without executing code) the login client part.

Comment: Can you post what the values you get are? If you don't specify a request code in the OpenRequest, it uses a default one (not random). Also, are you calling session.onActivityResult from your activity's onActivityResult?

Comment: @MingLi I've updated my question with the complete flow. Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Do the raw samples (supplied with the SDK) work for you? The first request code (64206) is 0xface in hex, which is the default code (you can see in Session.java). The second (129742) is 0x1face in hex, which I'm not sure where that comes from. If you can post a more complete code sample that reproduces the issue, I can try to narrow it down more.

Comment: @MingLi, were you able to narrow down the cause of this problem? I'm running into the same issue, except that the numbers I fight with are 62406 (0xface) and 326350 (0x4face), but I'm already calling super.onActivityResult as the only answer to this question suggest.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli This is a year old so you probably found the error of your ways. If anyone else (like me) stumbles upon this ridiculous error I found the error was that in my onActivityResult method in my activity I had written super.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, data) instead of super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data). Autocomplete! :)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem, except that in my case the offending `requestCode` was `326350` (`0x4face`). And I was indeed calling `super.onActivityResult`, so the [workaround proposed by Eric Savage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801050/) was already in place but not effective. Weirdest thing of all, this stuff did work just a couple of weeks ago, and the offending behaviour appeared without myself upgrading anything (Facebook SDK version, Android version, support library version, even the phone on which I'm developing/testing, are all the same as when I had it working).

However, Eric's answer contains other interesting hints, which I exploited to make my code work again. Basically, instead of passing the whole `requestCode` to `Session.onActivityResult`, I cut the lowest 16 bits and pass those only.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    int sanitizedRequestCode = requestCode % 0x10000;
    session.onActivityResult(this, sanitizedRequestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I do believe this is a bug that should be fixed in the Facebook SDK, and would insist to have it patched for the next release.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this same issue. The difference between 64206 (0xface) and 129742 (0x1face) is because FragmentActivity has tacked on an extra 0x10000 to determine which fragment it came from. This was resolved by making sure the super activity was called during onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You "Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode", as stated in FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment