# Facebook Android SDK: why is the Activity recreated before calling Fragment's onActivityResult?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I wrote a `Fragment` to manage Facebook log in/out with Facebook Android SDK 3.5.2, following the example given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/).

When the login process through Facebook web widgets is done, `MainActivity` is started again (`onCreate` is called).

Then in the example code if `savedInstanceState!=null` in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`, the `savedInstanceState` is checked to know if the existing `FacebookPrefsFragment` instance must be restored or if a new instance must be created:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
    .commit();
} else {
    // Or set the fragment from restored state info
    mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
}
```

My problem is that my `MainActivity` has many `Fragments`, and `savedInstanceState` can be not null not only when on the Facebook login process. So I have two questions:

- Why is `MainActivity` created again after the Facebook login process? Shouldn't just `FacebookPrefsFragment`'s `onActivityResult` be called?
- If it's going to be created, how can I know that it is because the Facebook SDK called it?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {       

            // If the Activity has been started after the Facebook login process, restart the FacebookPrefsFragment,
            // but how can I be sure that MainActivity has been called by the Facebook app?

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment facebookPrefsFragment = new FacebookPrefsFragment();       
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, facebookPrefsFragment, "facebookPrefsFragment");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else{
            // start other Fragment
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**FacebookPrefsFragment**

```
public class FacebookPrefsFragment extends Fragment{

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Logged in", MyApplication.LOG_LEVEL);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Logged out", MyApplication.LOG_LEVEL);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_prefs, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        authButton.setFragment(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of HOW facebook SDK will start your activity?

Comment: Using the code pointed to in my question, When the login is done, the "Class Name" set up in your Facebook android native app is called (see part 5 of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/)

Comment: Do you mean deep linking with facebook? Here is a way you do it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/#step7

Comment: No, I'll rewrite my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I found out why the `MainActivity` is recreated everytime: that's because I have the option "Don't keep activities" activated on my phone! Now I have to find out what to do in that case...

Comment: Usually, it's good to test with "Don't keep activities" turned ON because the Android OS can kill your activity (that's not showing) at any time. This really has nothing to do with the Facebook SDK, but your activity should be able to handle being recreated.

Comment: Yes, nothing to do with Facebook SDK, but it explains why the Activity was recreated every time!

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little dated but I figured I'd leave this here incase anyone comes across the issue I faced.  When the native Facebook app was not installed my app was being recreated and callbackManager.onActivityResult() kept returning false even though I had the correct request code and data.  I was able to resolve this issue by resetting and recalling the following if the initial call returned false:

```
facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, Activity.this);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to play around with the

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

See what is the request code while the application is coming from.
Source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/FacebookDialog.java#L210

I tested it a couple of months back, the requestCode is what you can use to identify whether is app is coming back from Facebook or not.

[Edit]

This is an ugly hack, but if `requestCode == 64206` then your activity just came back from facebook.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it's related to my questions.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130481/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-auth

Comment: My code works and `FacebookPrefsFragment`'s `onActivityResult` is called, but after `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`. My question is why the `Activity` is recreated, and how to know that it is recreated by the Facebook SDK.