# Session.getActiveSession() not retrieving the correct session in facebook sdk 3.5 android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have annoying problem with facebook sdk 3.5, I have made an example and it is works fine but from about a week it start behaving in a wrong way

the method `Session.getActiveSession()` return always a session with the following properties :

```
{
  Session state:OPENING, 
  token:
    {
      AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED 
      permissions:[]
    }, 
  appId: ??
}
```

after I enter my username and password and press the login button it direct me to the screen that say that the user already authorize this application and when get back to my activity it doesn't share or do anything

this problem happen when the sdk fail to connect to the installed application and open the web browser to take user data

My problem is the same as the question sent in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130481/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-auth).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Session.onActivityResult()...
}
```

Comment: I have already add this 

 if (requestCode == FACEBOOK_SDK_ACTION_CODE || requestCode == FACEBOOK_AUTH_ACTION_CODE) {
   
   Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this,
      requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

where FACEBOOK_SDK_ACTION_CODE = 64206 and FACEBOOK_AUTH_ACTION_CODE = 129742

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the request code for the openRequest somewhere?

Comment: check if your key hash is the same as you provided it properties on dev.facebook